# flutter_riverpod 1.0.0 prevents app from running in Chrome in debug mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, riverpod

Hi ran into this issue when I upgraded to flutter_riverpod 1.0.0
then saw this issue raised in the riverpod repo

[flutter_riverpod 1.0.0 ~Issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/889)

Then I saw that the owner of the repo closed the discussion about this leaving me clueless where to go next...

Will appreciate any help that I can get!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in dart sdk, not riverpod.
You should track (and upvote so it hopefully gets prioritized) the linked [dart sdk ticket](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47645) for this, which should resolve it when it's fixed.

Comment: thanks mate appreciate the help!

Comment: The issue was fixed a few days ago, but is currently available only on `flutter master`. Check [this comment in the original issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/889#issuecomment-971018136) for more info

Answer (score 0):

try to see if you've done all the required migrations possible
like when using consumerWidget the build method doesn't take ProviderBased object but now it's a WidgetRef you can now use the instance of WidgetRef and call read on it instead of context.read() to read the provider and use an instance of WidgetRef and call watch to see the changes in your provider
then run flutter clean after that run flutter pub get
see this link for more documentation [about riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/docs/getting_started)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed by the flutter team :D

Just switch to the master branch and pull the latest version of flutter (2.6.0-12.pre.757) dart (2.16)